# How to compare time in multiple rows using excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I need help to compare time in multiple rows in excel. I am creating a new rule in conditional formatting. I'm entering this formula in formula bar to compare time across multiple rows:

```
=IF($E$4:$E$6 > TIMEVALUE("8:30 am"),TRUE,FALSE)
```

but no cells are formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just avoid $ sign. I changed my above code into:

```
=IF(B2:B4 > TIMEVALUE("9:00 am"),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula in conditional formatting,

```
=$E2>TIMEVALUE("10:34 am")
```

I hope this serves the purpose.

Comment: how to apply above formula on multiple rows.

Comment: By selecting the range under "applies to" section of "Conditional Formatting Rules Manager".

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I found my answer and post it below.